# Googlebot used 9.60 GB bandwidth in a single day

Tags: wordpress, googlebot

I am facing a problem of googlebot data use of my one site. site url is http://kbsgloble.com/ and i have hosted with cPanel server and site is made by wordpress, now days i am faceing problem hight bandwidth issues.

check below my screenshot of states [image]

and don't want to block googlebot permanently so please any help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I doubt Google bot would normally do that. Perhaps you have a problem where some page(s) outputs too much data, or some malicious bot is using the Google Bots user agent string.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thanks for reply, you could be correct. so if you have any idea to fix out this problem then please suggest me.

Comment: I am not sure this is legitimate google bot. Looks more like a malware attack. Since you are powered with WordPress, install the plugin Wordfence and check the "Live Traffic" option to see which url this "Googlebot" is trying to reach.